# C++ copy constructor and type casting

Tags: c++, templates, casting, type-conversion, copy-constructor

Thanks for your help, I was able to summarize the following solution

Please correct me if I am wrong

Q. Explain at least three things that can go wrong

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
C mymin (const A& a, const B& b)
{
  if ( a < b )
      return (C) a;
  else
      return (C) b;
}
```

My answer is the following.

Please let me know if I got them all right.

1. < operator is not defined so we cannot compare the two objects with < operator
2. Types of A and B can be different, and the < operator is not defined for that
3. If C has a different type than A or B
   , type casting occurs that changes a or b that is defined constant
4. Type casting from A or B to C is not guaranteed
   , because the conversion constructor is not defined.
5. Copy constructor for A and B is not defined.
   Therefore we are just returning the shallowly copied one.
   Since it is a shallow copy
    , the shallow copy can be changed
    , and the original copy that is supposed to be constant can be changed too.

Thanks,

Comment: `x` and `y` are not declared? There are too many things that could be wrong in this code to make any answer meaningful.

Comment: Oh sorry I mis typed it. I corrected. THanks!

Comment: is return value of type 'G' also typo?

Comment: It was C. Soryy. I corrected it.

Comment: What if some C++ programmer came along and gave you a zen slap for using C-style casts? OTOH no, that would be things going right, not wrong.

Comment: Seems like all my answers are wrong... What else can I think of the possible errors?

Comment: Your template parameters are not in the optimal order. The only parameter that can never be deduced is `C` but as that is the last in the list it means that callers will always have to specify parameters `A` and `B` as well even if they could have been deduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> < operator is not defined so we cannot compare the two objects with < operator
>   Types of A and B can be different, and the < operator is not defined for that

It is unrelated, since even if both types are the same there still could be no operator< for them.

> If C has a different type than A or B , type casting occurs that changes a or b that is defined constant

Even if `C` is the same, there still will be constness loss.

> Type casting from A or B to C is not guaranteed , because the conversion constructor is not defined.

Typecasting itself is guaranteed, but with unpredictable results in case if types differ.

> Copy constructor for A and B is not defined. Therefore we are just returning the shallowly copied one. Since it is a shallow copy , the shallow copy can be changed , and the original copy that is supposed to be constant can be changed too.

There is no need for `A` or `B` to have copy constructor. The only constructor involved would be copy constructor of `C`, that will accept already C style cast `C` as param.

Comment: Casting doesn't change the source object unless the cast invokes a very strangely defined `operator X` or converting constructor. Also, the lack of constness doesn't affect the source object unless `C` is a reference type (where it still doesn't really affect the source object until someone "mis"-uses the resulting reference).

Comment: @CharlesBailey Yes it won't change object, as it will be used only to construct copy of `C` from whatever cast will provide, and I agree that in this case constness loss doesn't matter much. My note was rather to note that regardless of of `A` is the same as `C` or not, constness loss still occur.

Comment: Oh thanks, then what would be the answer for the question. That was all I could think of. But most of which is wrong....

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121 Apart from C style cast it is hard to tell without context. I'd vote for possibility of both a<b and b<a returning true, due to different implementations of operator< in A and B.